# How to prove left linear is left monotone?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semirings

In the paper  D. Wilding, M. Johnson, M. Kambites, Exact rings and semirings, J.Algebra 388, (2013), 324-337; [doi: j.jalgebra.2013.05.005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2013.05.005), [arXiv:1212.5358](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5358)] I found the following statement in page number 333 and 334:

A function $f:X \rightarrow Y $ between left $S$-modules $X$ and $Y$, for $S$ an idempotent semiring, will be called left monotone if $ax\leq x^{'} \Rightarrow a(fx)\leq fx^{'} ~ \forall ~ x, ~x^{'} \in X$ and all $a \in S$. It is clear that if $f$ is left linear then $f$ is left monotone. How to prove that anybody please help?

Comment: What's the difficulty? The definition of $ax\leq x'$ is $ax+x'=x'$, from which left-linearity of $f$ implies $a\,f(x)+f(x')=f(x')$ which means $a\,f(x)\leq f(x')$, QED.

Comment: I thought that $ax\leq x^{'}  \Rightarrow f(ax)\leq f(x^{'})$, then we have to use left linearity to complete the proof. In this way how to use monotone condition? So that I confused. According to your proof, I am very clear. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $ax≤x'$ is $ax+x′=x′$, from which left-linearity of $f$ implies $af(x)+f(x′)=f(x′)$ which means $af(x)≤f(x′)$.